# Google Analytics - How to get rid of "Pageviews" in a segment?

Tags: google, analytics

[image: How to get rid of this pageviews line?]

How do I get rid of this pageviews line? The other lines are comparing the pageviews of various "pages", but the blue line is the total overall from things not in my segment, and it's making it difficult to look at what I want to look at (seeing how pageviews compare between these pages over time)

Comment: It looks like you may have multiple segments applied at once.  Did you remove the "All Users" segment?

Answer (score 2):

These are two separate things. One being **Segments**, the other being **Metrics**.

The lines (metrics) can be switched to show page views, entrances, bounce rate, etc. the other one is called Segments, which groups pre-defined, rule-based traffic. In most cases, the blue line is assigned to the Segment **All Users**.

To remove that segment, you first need to add at least another segment to the report. By doing so, your segments become **removeable** (a dropdown caret appears on the top right of the segment block).

[image]

Just click on that caret next to **All Users**, and your blue line disappears.

Answer (score 1):

To remove pageviews from a segment, there should be a dropdown menu that has "pageviews" selected. You can either change this to a different option or you can click the little "x" next to the dropdown to remove this from your results.

[image]